# Middleware not working for API Routes

Tags: laravel-5

I have some middleware created to change database on the fly. Those middelwares are working fine in web.php But when i am using the same middleware in api.php they are not working.

Here is my code for `API.php`

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['subdomain_setup','auth:api','api'],'prefix'=>'v1'], function () {
    Route::get('getCoupons','Api\CouponAPI@getCoupons');
});
```

The Subdomain_setup middleware changes the databse according to the sub domain. But its not working with api routes so i am getting this error while accessing my api route

```
 Unknown column 'api_token' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `api_token` =
```

in the default connection users table does not have api_token so the database is not changing.

Answer (score 1):

auth:api middleware is using 'token' as a guard.

1. Make sure you are using 'passport' as 'driver' in config/auth in the api array.
2. Clear your cache like this: php artisan config:cache.
3. Send your api request including in the headers 'Authorization' Bearer (and your token)

Comment: I am not using Passport. I am using Token from api_token